# Android how to create notification that resumes activity instead of starting a new onw

Tags: java, android, notifications

So I've read the varios SO questions about this and I'ved tried to implement what they said and it doesnt work. When the notification is pressed i want it to pull back to the activity without clearing any of the EditTexts or turning off the toggle button. I.e resuming the activity from its last state. But so far my code doesnt work.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this,Locator.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                0, myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Comment: this code is in a service btw

Answer (score 0):

The Android OS is solely responsible for managing the lifecycle of an Activity and can kill an Activity at any time, thus there is no way to specify resume activity.  The OS will bring the requested activity to the top of the stack if it is still in memory; if the activity has been killed, it will be launched again and any saved state passed to it.

See [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Answer (score 0):

maybe
`<activity name="your activity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" />`
 is what you want. If activity not destroyed and in background, then it will appear, instead creating new.

Comment: where do i implement that line